# Can I touch my friend's breasts?

Tags: sex, islamic-basis

I am a teenage 14 year old boy and am curious if it is halal to touch a friend's breasts if she is unmarried and OK with it and not have intercourse or anything else. I am ashamed to ask this question but have no other way of finding an answer.

Answer (score 0):

hello I am sorry but you are not allowed to do that. if you are embarrassed then you can ask an online sheikh or imam for more info and be anonymous. it is very good that you are considering your actions.